# In Java 8, when I use stream() and filter(), can I keep objects related to the main one (as opposed to the object itself)?

Tags: lambda, collections, filter, java-8, java-stream

I'm using Java 8.  I realize I can cycle through a collection of objects and keep certain ones taht match a condition, which I've done below

```
final List<Organization> orgs = user.getOrganizations().stream().filter(org -> org.getParentOrg() != null && org.getParentOrg().getOrganizationType().isParent())
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<Organization>()));
```

but what if in some instances, I don't want to keep the object itself, but an object related to it?  That is if condition A is met, I want to keep "org", but if condition "B" is met, I want to keep "org.getParentOrg()", which is of the same type.  Does Java 8 provide a way to deal with this type of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Stream.map`, along with the ternary operator and a previous `Stream.filter` to discard elements that match neither `conditionA` nor `conditionB`:

```
List<Organization> orgs = user.getOrganizations().stream()
    .filter(org -> conditionA || conditionB)
    .map(org -> conditionA ? org : org.getParentOrg())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Or a single `.flatMap(org -> conditionA? Stream.of(org): conditionB? Stream.of(org.getParentOrg()): Stream.empty())`

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is that you use the `.reduce` method. You can try using it like this.[doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

```
stream.reduce(acollector, (a,v)->{
    if(v.isSomething()) a.add(v.getSomething());
    return a;
})
```